# Core Plot: Creating a CPTImage with imageWithCGImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, gradient, core-plot, cptimage

I am trying to create a bar with a gradient in core plot. I have the following code:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"orange_bar_graph"];

CPTImage *image = [CPTImage imageWithCGImage:img.CGImage];
image.tiled = NO;
CPTFill *areaFill = [CPTFill fillWithImage:image];

CPTBarPlot *plotOne = [[CPTBarPlot alloc] init];
plotOne.fill = areaFill;
plotOne.identifier = identifer[@"plotOne"];
```

However when I run the application it just shows the outline of the bars and the fill image is not being shown:
[image]

If I place it breaks points it shows that the image is created successfully and that the variable areaFill is not nil.

I did a post a while back where I had this similar code working. Here I use imageForPNGFile but that was just returning nil when trying it here: [Core Plot Gradient bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26013433/core-plot-gradient-bars)

However I can't seem to get it to work here.

Edit:

I have just ran this on the iPad 2 simulator and it works as expected. However when running on the iPad Air simulator it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `scale` of the image.

```
CPTImage *image = [CPTImage imageWithCGImage:img.CGImage scale:img.scale];
```

If you're using the latest Core Plot code (after release 1.5.1), you can load the image directly:

```
CPTImage *image = [CPTImage imageNamed:@"orange_bar_graph"];
```

Comment: Thanks for this Eric. I had found a solution to use a larger image for the lower retina screens which I was going to post. However your solution is an improvement on mine :-).